# Ruby thread does not execute

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have just added threads to an existing program using a model I have used before but this time the thread did not execute so I added

```
Thread.new {puts "thread" }
exit
```

at the top of the program and it exited without printing anything.

Pointers on diagnosing the problem solicited.

Linux (ubuntu) ruby 2.7

Answer (score 3):

The given code ..

```
Thread.new {puts "thread" }
exit
```

.. is not guaranteed to execute the `puts`. You must `join` the thread.

```
t = Thread.new {puts "thread" }
t.join # block until thread finishes
exit
```

Comment: Doh!  I do know about join...
the original code I was stepping through with the debugger and had the join  further down the program